# Is this beef rib ok?

Tags: food-safety, beef, ribs

I am cooking beef ribs for a chemo patient and don't want to take any chances. The fat on the ribs is bluish greenish.  See the photo.  Is it normal or rotten? The meat looks good.

[Imgur pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbw6O.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

While visual cues are often helpful, there is no way for anyone to let you know whether or not this product is a safety risk from the photo.  More important would be to know whether or not it has been handled and stored in a food-safe manner.

Comment: Good advice. There's nothing in the picture that suggests spoilage, but by the time visible signs appear, it's probably been bad for a while, so it's not safe to judge based solely on appearance.